# Lombok @SuperBuilder: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, annotations, lombok, builder, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have included @SuperBuilder for super class and all subclasses:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder

public abstract class Aggregator {
    private MyEnum myEnum;
    private MyPackage pck;
    private String device;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)

public class KNAggregator extends Aggregator {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String os;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private long vulnId;
    private Severity severity;
}
```

This code throws error:

> error: cannot find symbol
> @SuperBuilder
> symbol:   class AggregatorBuilder
> location: class Aggregator

What went wrong here?